# display custom messages within a oracle apex application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I know that when you are using the command prompt in oracle apex you can use the below code to output messages but how is this done within an oracle apex application. thanks in advance

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('example message');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can display a message in Apex. Here's a few off the top of my head:

1. Add a region based on a PL/SQL block that calls `htp.p()`
2. Add a Display Item based on the value you want to show, or set its value in a page load process.
3. Add javascript to call `alert()` to show a really basic popup message

How you do this depends on *when* you need the message to appear, and *how*.

Comment: I am wanting to display the results of a plsql function

Comment: then you can call your function and use any of the methods I've listed here to render the result